# Grid-based Game

Tags: libraries, 2d-games

I am trying to make a **graphical** grid-based game. It is supposed to look somewhat like Conway's Game of Life, with a simplistic grid consisting of cells, which can be individually turned on and off either by the player or programmatically. There is not much more to the grid itself; the actual gameplay is controlled entirely by the backend.

I can use any programming language (preferably Python, Java, or C) to make the grid, but I have no idea about how to get started. I looked at some of the options I have:

- Java's 2D graphics library
- Using GTK or Qt in C/C++
- Python and PyGTK or PyGObject
- Python and PyGame

But the main issue is that I do not want anything too complicated or heavy, because this grid will only be used for two purposes:

- to *design* shapes before gameplay
- to display a small section of the grid during gameplay, only if anyone is interested (otherwise the game can go on rapidly without any human interference or display)

This grid would display a maximum area of around 300x300, scrollable but not resizable. If it is being used for designing, the player should be able to click on cells to change their status and at the end, save the shape (in some internal format) to a file. If it is showing a game in progress, it would have to be programmatically updated from 1 to 5 updates per second.

Here is a rough picture of what it should look like, with the yellow representing 'on' cells. This image is a screenshot of [golly](http://sourceforge.net/projects/golly/), and I don't know how golly does it because the code is above me. [image: what it should look like]

Answer (score 1):

simplest way would be to create s simple two dimentinal array with O and X
like this:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX000XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

and just print it on the console.

otherwise you need graphical library.

java has:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html

phyton got:
http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html

just create a "draw shape1 at location" and "drawshape2  at location" methods.
and draw!

Comment: If I have to draw a lot of these shapes, won't it take a little too much time? And also, these libraries are overkill for what I'm using them for. However, I'll see if it works out.